# Phase - My images dont load

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I´m new in phaser. I started to watch youtube series and I have first
problem with it.
My background image dont load.
I have this js code

```
/* global Phaser */

var game = new Phaser.Game(1200,600, Phaser.AUTO);

var GameState = {
    preload : function(){
        this.load.image('background','assets/images/background.png');
    },
    create: function() {
        this.background = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
    },
    update : function() {

    }
};

game.state.add('GameState',GameState);
```

my index.php code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs' dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale-1, user-scalable=no'/>

        <title>8. úkol</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/phaser.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'>

        </script>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

My background image has size 600x135

Comment: Hi i saw u figure it out ur problem one more thing, `game.state.add('GameState', GameState, true)` the third option adding state is taking a boolean value. which true means start this state :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Hi just copy all this and it should solve your problem now Phaser its a really interesting framework please fell free to send me a direct msg on any questions Im pretty new to this to and I'll be more than happy to show you all I know have a nice day!

```
   /* global Phaser */



var GameState = {
preload : function(){
    this.load.image('background','assets/images/background.png');
},
create: function() {
    this.background = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
},
update : function() {

}
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(1200,600, Phaser.AUTO);  //<--- use it down
                                                   //    here its neater
game.state.add('GameState',GameState);
game.state.start('GameState')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding this to code

```
game.state.start('GameState');
```

Comment: FYI, you should be able to mark this as the answer so people know this question has been successfully answered.